# Laravel: redirecting to a specific url, from controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm having troubles to just redirect to a url from a controller.

This is my trigger:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('creategroup") }}">
```

Then, this is the catcher:

```
Route::post('/creategroup', 'GroupController@store');
```

And finally, this is my method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    /* bla bla bla */
    return Redirect::to('/users/'.$request->id.'/groups/');
}
```

But it doesn't work, the url just stops in localhost/creategroup and it shows a page that say that the page has expired, and it doesn't redirect to any place. Help please.

Comment: Hi, you get into your store method right?

Comment: Can you try following `return Redirect::to('users/'.$request->id.'/groups/');`

Comment: Yes I can, I test changing the post for a get, and then it works

Comment: It is better to define a route and redirect with redirect()->route() and send id paremeter as rout() method parameters.

Comment: ah of course you used post missed that one, so it works now?

Comment: It works whit 'GET', but is a form and is necessary to use 'POST'.

Comment: I try return Redirect::to("/users/{$request->id}/groups/"); it doesn't work, stills stops in /creategroup and showing that the page expires

Comment: Just a quick recommendation, you should consider generating url's with laravel helper methods, like this `return redirect()->action('UsersController@groups', ['id'=>$request->id]);`. In the blade templates, you can use `action` helper function like this:  `action('UsersController@groups', ['id'=>$id])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with csrfToken.

Have you added the field on the form?

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf)

Comment: @iFredus Glad to hear that  Consider marking the answer as correct to help next people find a quick solution 

Comment: Done, you are the best

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to the first backslash, try following:

```
return redirect('users/'.$request->id.'/groups');
```

Comment: Did it work after you changed your route from get to post I could have a look tomorrow again I have to leave now sorry

Comment: No, it doens't work with post, with get it works fine